# is it possible to get the same message into your App that you are receiving in Messages App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, imessage-extension

I have developed an messaging application, now i want while sending a message from our App to any of our contacts from address book if that contact doesn't have our App then that message should be sent into the default messages App. I know that is possible but the other part is if someone don't have the App in their device and trying to send a message from messages App and the receiver has our App then that user should receiver should receive that message into our App as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**Not Possible**

iOS app can access only those data for which Apple supplies a documented public API. iOS can not access outside of the sandbox until Apple provides a public API for it. So intercepting/reading an incoming SMS not possible.

Comment: Can we do it using iMessage-extensions?

Comment: I don't think So, You cant find and bring particular message conversation to your app with iMessage-Extension,